# Tomcat - WELD workaround for asynchronous requests

Tags: tomcat, cdi, weld2

I have a REST application implemented with WELD 3.0.5 and RestEasy 3.6.1 running on Tomcat 9.

For the asynchronous requests, Tomcat fires the request destroyed event in a different thread than the one that fired the initialized event. 
In this case, WELD, which uses `ThreadLocals`, does not deactivate the request context and, as a result, the bean disposal methods are not called.

See: [What do WELD-000225, WELD-000335 and WELD-000715 warnings mean?](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/)

and 
[Tomcat Bug 57314](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57314)

My application depends on the container lifecycle events to close resources and clean up, so I need a way to make everything work for async requests as well. The solution I came up with is to add a `WebFilter` that invalidates the current request context at the end of the execution chain.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws Exception {

    BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    AlterableContext context = (AlterableContext) beanManager.getContext(RequestScoped.class);
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        if (request.isAsyncStarted()) {
            AbstractBoundContext<?> ctxt = (AbstractBoundContext<?>) delegate;
            ctxt.invalidate();
            ctxt.deactivate();
            ctxt.cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

That does a pretty good job discarding the beans and removing some of the thread-local variables. Unfortunately some of the variables remain tied to the pooled thread 
and Tomcat complains about it:

```
SEVERE: The web application [cdi-weld] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3d97cd8b]) and a value of type [org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.Counter] (value [org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle$Counter@43a15b16]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 02, 2018 10:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [cdi-weld] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@21d33dd8]) and a value of type [org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext.ManagedState] (value [org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext$ManagedState@2a336421]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 02, 2018 10:43:55 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [cdi-weld] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@294b0f79]) and a value of type [org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.ConversationContextActivator$$Lambda$555/1676983761] (value [org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.ConversationContextActivator$$Lambda$555/1676983761@60fb88ad]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

My understanding is that the ThreadLocals get overwritten for each request so that's not exactly a memory leak, but I am still not 100% happy with this solution.

Does anyone know a better way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The below information is not a solution I have tried, but it is my best shot at how you could remedy some of it.

`org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.Counter` you probably won't be able to fix, or at least I don't know how.

But the other two are different contexts and you might be able to address it by deactivating them like you did with request context.

`org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractManagedContext.ManagedState`
You will have to dig into what context this actually is. Session or conversation is my guess. Try using `BeanManager` to retrieve contexts for scopes you know are there and see. A little bit of debug goes a long way.

`org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.ConversationContextActivator$$Lambda$555/1676983761` This should be conversation context (probably `LazyHttpConversationContextImpl`). Releasing that context could make this go away.

Comment: You're right. If I cleanup the Session and Conversation contexts I get rid of most of the thread locals. In the end I'm left only with the Counter. I was hoping there was a better fix.

Comment: Well, Weld cannot do much for you there since it is servlet-agnostic and doesn't know Tomcat. Besides IMO it's Tomcat doing it wrong here...